# Jsoup in Android, extracting the "middle word" in text from an element after title=

Tags: android, element, jsoup, extract, html-table

Im making an Android App and i need help with targeting a specific text in an Element

This is where im at:

```
Elements bookietemp = item.getElementsByClass("name");
String bookie1 = bookietemp.select("a[title]").first().text(); //This dosnt work
Log.d("test", bookie1);
```

I have tried with the above, but it dosnt work or return anything:

"bookietemp" will contain the following code, from this i want to extract only: "Toto" or "Tobet" (The second word/the word after "Open ", after title=)

This is the value from "bookietemp"

```
<a rel="nofollow" class="name" title="Open Toto website!" target="_blank" href="/bookmakers/toto/web/"><span class="BK b6">&nbsp;</span></a>
<a rel="nofollow" class="name" title="Open Tobet website!" target="_blank" href="/bookmakers/tobet/web/"><span class="BK b36">&nbsp;</span></a>
```

And my full code is here:

```
public class AsyncTaskActivity extends Activity {

    Button btn_start;

    TextView state;
    TextView output;

    ProgressDialog dialog;
    Document doc;
    String test;
    Element test2;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_async_task);

        btn_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
        state = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.state);
        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
        btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                btn_start.setEnabled(false);
                new ShowDialogAsyncTask().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private class ShowDialogAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

        ArrayList<String> arr_linkText=new ArrayList<String>();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // update the UI immediately after the task is executed
            super.onPreExecute();

            Toast.makeText(AsyncTaskActivity.this, "Invoke onPreExecute()",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            output.setText("Please Wait!");
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... String) {
//          String linkText = "";

            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.bmbets.com/sure-bets/").get();
//               linkText = el.attr("href");
//               arr_linkText.add(linkText);


                Elements widgets = doc.getElementsByClass("surebets-widget");

                for (Element widget : widgets){
                    //Log.d("test", el.toString());
                    Elements items = widget.getElementsByClass("item"); //Dette giver dig ca 8 items.
                    for (Element item : items)
                    {
                        Elements matchtemp = item.getElementsByClass("odd");
                        String matchname = matchtemp.select("a[title]").first().text();
                        Log.d("test", matchname);

                        //Here is the problem
                        Elements bookietemp = item.getElementsByClass("name");
                        String bookie1 = bookietemp.select("a[title]").first().text();
                        Log.d("test", bookie1);

                        Elements tipvals = item.getElementsByClass("tip-val");
                        if (tipvals.size() == 2)
                        {
                            Log.d("test", "Head to Head kamp");
                            Element tipval1 = tipvals.get(0);
                            String oddshome = tipval1.text().trim();
                            Element tipval2 = tipvals.get(1);
                            String oddsaway = tipval2.text().trim();
                            Log.d("test", oddshome + " " + oddsaway);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Log.d("test", "3 way");
                            Element tipval1 = tipvals.get(0);
                            String oddshome = tipval1.text().trim();
                            Element tipval2 = tipvals.get(1);
                            String oddsdraw = tipval2.text().trim();
                            Element tipval3 = tipvals.get(2);
                            String oddsaway = tipval3.text().trim();
                            Log.d("test", oddshome + " " + oddsdraw + " " + oddsaway);
                            }

                    }

//               arr_linkText.add(linkText);
                }

    //          return test2;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return arr_linkText;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            // // progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
            // // txt_percentage.setText("downloading " +values[0]+"%");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
            // super.onPostExecute(result);
            Toast.makeText(AsyncTaskActivity.this, "Invoke onPostExecute()",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            state.setText("Done!");
            //output.setText(result);
            for (String temp_result : result){
                output.append (temp_result +"\n");

            }

            btn_start.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

Note i have something a bit similar to extract another text, which is working:

```
Elements matchtemp = item.getElementsByClass("odd");
String matchname = matchtemp.select("a[title]").first().text();
Log.d("test", matchname);
```

Comment: Or just how to get the entire text after title,  and then filter it afterwards..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out myself using:

```
Elements bookietemp = item.getElementsByClass("name");
String bookie1 = bookietemp.attr("title"); //This gets the full line
String arr[] = bookie1.split(" ", 3);   //This splits the word in 3                 
String theRest = arr[1];  //This selects the second word
```

EDit:
If anyone have a simplier way, or a way to combine these lines im still interrested